# Firebase authentication - identity platforom - pricing

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-identity

Still, I can't understand about firebase pricing on authentication with the identity platform.

I have a question. I own an app that integrates Firebase authentication which is the type of Social, Anonymous, and Email+Password.

The question is did you charge only sign-ups or sign-in or both using either type of authentication mentioned above? Why should I ask? Because Auth0 offers only charges applicable on sign-ups and unlimited logins.

Another question, Do I get charged to check if a user is signed in or not using

```
FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
updateUI(currentUser);
```

So, kindly request you to clarify it. Thank you.

```
FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
updateUI(currentUser);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I own an app that integrates Firebase authentication which is the type of Social, Anonymous, and Email+Password the question is did you charge only sign-ups or sign-in or both using either type of authentication mentioned above?

As far as I understand from the official documentation regarding the [pricing overview](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/pricing):

> Any account that has **signed in** within a given month is considered an active user.

A sign-up operation can also be considered a sign-in operation. The difference between these two operations is that the sign-up operation also creates the user in Firebase authentication.

> Another question, Do I get charged to check if a user is signed in or not using

To check if a user is signed in or not, you only have to check the user object against nullity, which is not a chargeable operation.